# Is there a way to represent each model of device in stack for each category column differently? Using Echarts.js

Tags: bar-chart, echarts, stacked-chart

I want to represent, for example: Apple is brand and it has categories like iPhone, iPad ... and each category has different device like iPhone 12 Pro, iPad pro, iPad air ...
and I want to represent them in stacked on each column, [This is what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs83H.png)
-> And ->  [And I have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2VHK.png) Here I put category  iPhone as total amount of cost of (iPhone 12 Pro, iPhone 13 ...)

[I want this kind of bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP2sG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, here's an example:

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-y-category-stack

Comment: Yeah I see this but it is not I wanted to do, please check I added new photo that show the chart which I want

Answer (score 0):

you can check this,

https://apache.github.io/echarts-handbook/en/how-to/chart-types/bar/stacked-bar/

you must insert the same value of `stack` variable. if at the first data you add value stack of variable is 'x', you must add same value at the second data.